# Finding the longest length of upper case letter in string using Python

Tags: python

I've been given an assignment to find the longest length of upper case letters in string using Python.

Supposing I have a new email, how can I calculate the following features?:

- capital_run_length_average: continuous
- capital_run_length_longest: continuous
- capital_run_length_total: continuous

Here is a link to the Spambase dataset I'm working with:
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Spambase

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How to find the longest length of upper case letter in string using Python.

Comment: I've tried to clean up your question via an edit, but it's really incomplete and in need of additional information from you.

Comment: I have this string HUSSamASFRFTF . How to find the longest upper case length . I the previous example will be 7

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably be best served by a regular expression in this and many similar cases.

```py
import re  # library for regular expression wrangling

def get_max_uppercase_run_from_string(s):
    # construct a list of all the uppercase segments in your string
    list_of_uppercase_runs = re.findall(r"[A-Z]+", s)

    # find out what the longest string is in your list
    longest_string = max(list_of_uppercase_segments, key=len)

    # return the length of this string to the user
    return len(longest_string)
```

Here's a live example of the regular expression you can play with:
https://regex101.com/r/0LUYEo/1

Comment: Splendid - please use the little checkmark to the left of this answer to mark your question as solved.

Comment: Could please explain how to extract the following features from string

Comment: capital_run_length_average: continuous
capital_run_length_longest: continuous
capital_run_length_total: continuous

Comment: `re.findall(regex, string)` will return a list containing each matching part of the given string. In the given case, this is `['HUSS', 'ASFRFTF']`. My example provides the longest run as `longest_string` by finding the max value according to its **len**gth. Consider creating a new function for each extract which accepts a list and returns the values you need. The total run length will just be the sum of all the lengths (11), and the average will be this number divided by the count (2). Typecast your divisor as a `float()` to prevent integer truncation `11/2==5` while `11/float(2) == 5.5`.

Comment: % 1 continuous integer [1,...] attribute of type capital_run_length_longest
% = length of longest uninterrupted sequence of capital letters . How to calculate from given string

Comment: I can help you, but I need to understand what part you do not understand. Lets chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149899/discussion-for-45249629

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: Any idea to calculate the features

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I don't believe I can assist you further until you have a higher reputation. I hope the lengthy comment above is sufficient. If you are still stuck, try asking a new question, but you will need to make it more clear than this one by including a code example of you work. "What do you expect this code to do that it does not do?"

Comment: I want to extract features from email which is in string format so according to arff from this link https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/spambase       I extracted from email text 54 features from python code so I need the last three excluding class feature .What is mean by the last three feature in above link